# Intuition/explanation of totally disconnected sets (or subsets of R).

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, measure-theory

I'm trying to understand Rudin's solution to an analysis problem ([Construction of a Borel set with positive but not full measure in each interval](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/57317/construction-of-a-borel-set-with-positive-but-not-full-measure-in-each-interval)) and the term totally disconnected is not something I've seen.  Resources have been unhelpful. Could someone explain the intuition behind this property (in regards to $\mathbb{R}$ or Cantor set, for example)? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Totally disconnected is sort of opposite to connected.

Being connected is sometimes a counterintuitive concept. So let's have a look at a different, yet similar and more intuitive idea: path connectedness.

A space is path connected if any two points can be connected via continuous path. Examples are: $\mathbb{R}$, the sphere $S^n$ and a singleton $\{*\}$. It is easy to write the opposite of that: a space it totally path disconnected if no two distinct points can be connected via a path. Examples are: $\mathbb{Q}$, the Cantor set, any discrete space (note funny fact: single point is the only nonempty space that is both connected and totally disconnected at the same time). An example of something in-between is $[0,1]\cup[2,3]$.

I often imagine it like this: if I land on a totally disconnected space then regardless of the landing point I cannot move anywhere. I have to jump.

We can use this idea for normal connectedness as well. Except that first we have to somehow translate "connectedness" into a relationship between points. And we do that by realizing that a space is connected if and only if any two points belong to a connected subset. This gives us a way to introduce the opposite: a space is totally disconnected if no two distinct points lie in a connected subset.

Examples I gave you earlier are examples for connected and totally disconnected spaces as well (although these concepts do not pairwise coincide).

Read more here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Totally_disconnected_space

Comment: What gives Rudin the ability to claim that a union of CTDP (compact totally disconnected positive) sets is also totally disconnected? Is it compactness or positive measure?  (or perhaps both?) I think both R/Q and Q are totally disconnected wrt [0,1]. But their union is not.

Comment: @Muselive you are right but neither $R/Q$ nor $Q$ is compact. Compactness is crucial, see this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2728747/union-of-two-compact-totally-disconnected-sets-in-mathbbr-is-totally-discon

Answer (score 2):

It helps to recall the definition of connected first.  A space $X$ is connected if it's impossible to find disjoint, non-empty opens $U$ and $V$ so that $X = U\cup V$.  So $X$ is disconnected if there are some points $x,y\in X$ and disjoint open neighbourhoods $U\ni x$ and $V\ni y$ so that $X = U\cup V$.

Totally disconnected spaces take this further.  $X$ is totally disconnected if for *every* $x$ and $y$ there are $U$ and $V$ as above.

Answer (score 1):

As the term says, totally disconnected literally means that every point is not "connected" to any other point (possibly, the notion of totally path-disconnected is easier to visualize: no two points can be joined by a continuous path). A good example to keep in mind is $\mathbb{Q}$ (with the topology inherited from the real line). For every two rational numbers $a$ and $b$, you can find an irrational number $\tau \in (a,b)$, so that

$$[a,b] \cap \mathbb{Q} = ([a,\tau] \cap \mathbb{Q}) \sqcup ([\tau,b] \cap \mathbb{Q}).$$

This shows that every non-empty, closed interval in $\mathbb{Q}$ can be decomposed into two disjoint, non-empty, closed intervals, which is not possible, for instance, in the real line. And you can repeat this procedure again and again: intervals disintegrate in your hands, until (in the limit) you are left with just points.

Answer (score 1):

Totally disconnected $X$ means that the canonical map $X \to \pi^0 (X)$ is an homeomorphism.